# Java 8 default interface method overload and map the return type

Tags: java, java-8, interface

I am trying to overload the default method of Java 8 as shown below

```
public interface IProductOperation {
    @Post(consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    default Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(@NotBlank Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files, @Body ProductViewModel model){
        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.accepted()); // This should not be like this. It should return actual response from the backend.
    };
}
```

What should be the return type of above method. It should return `Maybe<HttpResponse<?>>`. Below is the class that implements this interface.

```
@Controller("/api/${api.version:v1}/product")
public class ApiGatewayProductController implements IProductOperation {
    private final IProductClient iProductClient;
    @Override
    public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(@NotBlank Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files, @Body ProductViewModel model){
        return this.iProductClient.post(files, model);
    }
}
```

Another controller that implements the same interface but with overloaded method

```
@Controller("/product")
public class ProductController implements IProductOperation {
    public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(@Body MultipartBody file){
        LOG.info(String.format("Controller --> Creating new product"));
        return iProductManager.Create(new ProductViewModel("", ProductOptionViewModel.SIZE)).flatMap(item -> {
                    if (item != null)
                        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.created(item, new URI(item.id())));
                    else
                        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.serverError());
                }
        );
    }
}
```

The return type of default method in the interface should match with the above method return type. How should I write the interface return type ?

Comment: If I understood the problem clearly, you might just be looking for `interface IProductOperation<T>` and then `Maybe<HttpResponse<T>> post` for both the overloaded methods.

Comment: @Naman How about the return type from the default method of interface?